# If $p$ is prime, show that $p\mid a^2 \implies p\mid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, square-numbers

This might seem like a trivial question, but I am not very good at mathematics. If I am supposed to show that:

> If $p$ is prime show that $p\mid a^2 \implies p\mid a$

I would do like this (I do not even know if it is a valid way to show the statement);

If $p$ is prime then $p\mid p$. So if $p\mid a^2$ it means that $a^2$ must have at least one factor $p$ such that $p\mid a^2$ and due to the fact that $a^2 = a \times a$, it follows that $p = a$. Thus $p\mid a$.

But that is not a formal proof, right? It is more like an informal proof. So my question is if there is a more formal approach to show that:

> If $p$ is prime show that $p\mid a^2 \implies p\mid a$

I know that there exist different methods to show divisibility, but due to the obviousness of the statement I have a very hard time showing the statement without using a lot of words.

Comment: Bezout's identity?

Comment: What is your definition of prime? This follows directly from the fact that $p$ divides a product if and only if $p$ divides one of the factors.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910782/prove-forall-n-in-mathbbn3n2-rightarrow-3n?noredirect=1#comment3922039_1910782

Comment: If this is over the integers, then the fundamental theorem of arithmetic seems like the easiest way to go.

Comment: A Crostul said, this follows at once from the standard definition of prime element, both in ring theory and in number theory. To know how to help the OP *must* say what his definition of prime is.

Comment: @LoganToll You have shown the implication in the wrong order.

Comment: My definition of a prime number in this case would be: _a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself._

Comment: Perhaps the contrapositve would be easier to show? If $p$ does not divide $a,$ then $p$ does not divide $a^2$. As @AlexisOlson said, this isn't too hard to prove using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @LoganToll  You are proving the converse of the statement required. You need to start by assuming $p \lvert a^2$.

Comment: Thought it would be interesting/helpful to the OP to point out that more generally, if $p \lvert ab$ then $p \lvert a$ or $p \lvert b$. Even more generally, if $n \lvert ab$ and $\gcd(a,n) = 1,$ then $n \lvert b.$ This is a result known as Euclid's Lemma and a standard proof using Bezout's identity can be found on Wikipedia.

Comment: "\mid" is preferred in MathJax to write "divides" symbol.

Comment: It is not a correct proof, formal or informal.

Comment: @user254665 what is wrong with it?

Comment: (1). "So if $p|a^2$  then $a$ has at least one factor $p$ with $p|a^2\;$" is a tautology. (2).  "Due to $a^2=a\times a$ it follows that $p=a. $" Huh? How did $p$ get to be equal to $a$?  What if $p=3$ and $a=6$?

Comment: @user254665 I see, you are correct I cannot say that $p=a$.

Answer (score 2):

As $p|a^2$ we write $a^2=pb$. As the left hand side is a square, we write $b=pc^2$. Therefore $a^2=p^2c^2\to a=pc$, hence $p|a$.

Comment: That's quite a leap to say $b=pc^2$.

Answer (score 2):

A quick proof. Since $\textbf{F}_p=\textbf{Z}/p\textbf{Z}$ is a field, and $a^2=0$ in $\textbf{F}_p$, we have $a=0$ in $\textbf{F}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

If P doesn't divide a, then
a=m.p, where m is a non integer rational number.
Multiplying a both sides

a^2 = m.a.p

m.a will still be a non integer  rational number. Since m has p in denominator and p cannot divide a. So a^2 has non integer quotient when divided by p.

Hence p should divide a, for it to divide a^2.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $p\not\mid a$. Then $p$ is not in the factorization of $a$. Since $a^2$ has the same factors as $a$ with exponents doubled, $p$ is not in the factorization of $a^2$, so $p\not\mid a^2$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [fundamental theorem of arithemtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), $a$ is the unique product of $k$ primes

$$a = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i} = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$

Then we can write

$$a^2 = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{2\alpha_i} = p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{2\alpha_k}$$

Now if $p\ |\ a^2 = \prod_i p_i^{2\alpha_i}$, then $p$ must be one of the $p_i$ since the prime factorization is unique.

Therefore we have $p\ | \ \prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i} = a$.

---

Let's apply this to a simple example. Let $p = 3$ and $a = 60$. Then

$$a = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \text{ and } a^2 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2$$

Since $3$ divides $a^2$ we know that $3$ is one of the primes in the factorization of $a^2$. Thus $3$ is also one of the primes in the factorization of $a$ and therefore divides $a$.

Comment: I'm just guessing from what the OP said and wrote, but I'm guessing that OP does not know the "indexed product" symbol, and is even less likely to make sense of the indexed product without bounds on the index. But OP can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was writing the same and think it is a short and good answer

Comment: Good enough. Let's see whether OP selects it or corrects my conjecture about level of understanding.

Comment: @John Hughes you are correct. I do not know the "indexed product" symbol and I cannot say that I understand this argument.

Comment: I've expanded the notation in an edit. I will add a more explicit example.

Comment: There is some amount of circularity involved here. The unique factorization theorem is itself dependent on the property of primes that if $p \mid ab $ then either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

Comment: That the "factorization is unique" is surprisingly difficult to express precisely...but it's right at the heart of your proof.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p \nmid a$ then we know that $p$ and $a$ have no common factor and hence their GCD is $1$. Therefore there are integers $x, y$ with $px + ay = 1$. Now multiplying by $a$ we get $$apx + a^{2}y = a$$ and since $p \mid a^{2}$ we have an integer $n$ such that $a^{2} = np$ and hence $$apx + npy = a$$ or $$p(ax + ny) = a$$ so that $p \mid a$ and we reach a contradiction. It follows that $p \mid a$.

Comment: You'll probably want to reference [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for your statement.

Comment: @AlexisOlson: I knew this basic result for years without knowing that it had a name. Thanks for reference.

Answer (score 1):

*An elementary proof*, without the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

This proof only uses  $\mathbf N$ being *well ordered* and its consequence: *Euclidean division*.

Consider the set $\;E=\bigl\{x\in \mathbf N^*\enspace\text{such that}\enspace p\mid xa\bigr\}$.

This set is not empty, since it contains $p$ and $a$. So it contains a smallest element, $b$.

**Claim**: $\;b$ divides every element of $E$.

Indeed, let $x$ be any element of $E$. Euclidean division gives equality $\;x=qb+r$, $\;0\le r<b$. As $x$  and $b$ lie in $E$, so does $r$, unless $r=0$. But this is impossible, since $b$ is the *smallest* element of $E$. Thus, $r=0$, i.e. $b$ divides $x$.

In particular, $b$ divides $p$. As $p$ is prime, this means $b=1$ or $b=p$.

If $b=1$, by definition of $E$, it means $p$ divides $1\cdot a=a$.

If $b=p$, $\;p$ divides $a$ by the claim, since $a\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if one assumes ring-theoretic [definition of prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element), this whole exercise is trivial. So, we obviously won't, we will assume that "prime" means positive integer with exactly two divisors in $\Bbb N$.

One needs to be careful not to fall into circularity here, so let me introduce terminology.

- We will call positive integer $p$ **$\Bbb N$-prime** if $p$ has
  exactly two divisors in $\Bbb N$.
- We will call (integer) $x$ **prime** if $x\mid ab\implies x\mid a$
  or $x\mid b$.
- We will call $x\in \Bbb Z\setminus\{0,\pm 1\}$ **irreducible** if
  $x = ab\implies a =\pm 1$ or $b = \pm 1$.

Thus, we can reformulate your exercise as

> Every $\Bbb N$-prime $p$ is prime in $\Bbb Z$.

because we would then have $p|a^2 \implies p\mid a$ or $p\mid a$.

---

> **Lemma.** $x$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z$ if and only if $|x|$ is $\Bbb N$-prime.

*Proof.* Assume that $x$ is irreducible and that $d\mid |x|$ in $\Bbb N$. Then $x = \pm nd$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, but since $x$ is irreducible, $d = 1$ or $n= 1$, i.e. $d = 1$ or $d = |x|$.

Conversely, if $|x|$ has exactly two divisors in $\Bbb N$, and $x = ab$, then $|a|,|b|\in\{ 1,|x|\}$, but that means that either $a = \pm 1$ or $b=\pm 1$.

---

In general, we know that every [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) is [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), and also, we know that in UFD $x$ is prime [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element#Relationship_with_prime_elements) $x$ is irreducible.

Thus, if we can prove that $\Bbb Z$ is Euclidean domain, then it is UFD, and thus if $p$ is $\Bbb N$-prime, it is irreducible in $\Bbb Z$ by our Lemma, and hence prime, which would finish the proof by the above remark.

> **Theorem.** $\Bbb Z$ is Euclidean domain with Euclidean function $f\colon\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb N$, $f(x) = |x|$.

*Sketch of proof.* Let $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ with $b\neq 0$. For simplicity let us assume that $a,b>0$.

We want to show that there exists $q,r\in \Bbb N$ such that $a = bq + r$ and $0\leq r < b$. Let us define $q = \min\{n\in\Bbb N\,|\, nb > a\} - 1$ (existence of $q$ is guaranteed by [well-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) of $\Bbb N$) and define $r = a - bq$. Then we have $$bq \leq a < b(q+1)\implies 0\leq a - bq < b \implies 0\leq r < b.$$

General case where $a,b$ are not necessarily positive can be deduced from this by playing with absolute value.

Of course, for $a,b\neq 0$, $f(a)\leq f(ab) \iff |a| \leq |ab| \iff 1\leq |b|$ and we are done.

Comment: I like this answer, although in some ways it reminds me of the title of a book I once saw: *Mathematics made difficult*. :)  I like it partly because although it involves many ideas that are probably unfamiliar to OP, it does so in a very clear way, with pointers to explanations of these ideas.

Comment: I like the reference to *Mathematics made difficult* :) To be honest, I've never seen the actual formal proof of all this stuff (for $\Bbb Z$, I mean), so I just wrote it from top of my head. Essentially, this all comes down to $\Bbb Z$ being GCD domain, and it might be easier to prove that and avoid the rest of generalities.