# Alternative proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

If we set $\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b$ are positive and coprime, we get $2 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$. However, as $a^2,b^2$ must also be coprime, this fraction can only be an integer if $b^2 = 1$, so $b=1$. Then $a^2 = 2$, which is clearly false as $a^2 > 3$ for $a > 2$ and $a$ is not 0 or 1.

Comment: How do you get the relation a>2?

Comment: @RamanujanXV Because a is assumed to be an integer and cannot be 0 or 1

Comment: Yep, I'm just taking cases on the positive integers.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I understand that, but why not a$\geq$2?

Comment: You might find this question of mine interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311228/what-is-the-most-unusual-proof-you-know-that-sqrt2-is-irrational

Comment: @RamanujanXV Well tbh I think the last bit in OP's proof can be tidied up. OP can just say it is clear $b\neq 1$ since $2$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I agree with you.

Comment: The crucial claim that $(a,b)=1\Rightarrow (a^2,b^2)=1$ requires *proof*.  This well-known proof is already posted here *many* times, e.g. see the linked dupes. Please search for answers before posting questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks okay to me. You can simply state that $a^2,b^2$ being coprime implies they cannot cancel out to an integer since $b\neq 1$, which is proof 4 [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml).

Comment: This gives a very easy proof for any number which isn't a perfect square right? Essentially if the square root is not an integer, it can't be rational.

Comment: @FnarkMan yes it extends to any number not a perfect square

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).