# Can this proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational be rewritten using only integers?

Tags: proof-writing, radicals, integers, irrational-numbers

Can this proof that
$\sqrt{2}$
is irrational
be rewritten using only integers?

Most proofs that
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational
start with assuming that
$2=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$
and derive a contradiction.

For a nice collection,
see my question here:
[What is the most unusual proof you know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311228/what-is-the-most-unusual-proof-you-know-that-sqrt2-is-irrational)

These proofs generally
only use properties
of the integers.

However
the following proof
uses the actual
$\sqrt{2}$
and thus requires
the actual square roots
between integers.

So I wondered if this
could be modified
so it did not require
non-integers.

I will write the proof
in this more general form:

If $n$ and $k$
are positive integers
such that
$k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$
then $\sqrt{n}$
is irrational.

Proof:

Suppose
$\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{a}{b}$,
so $a=b\sqrt{n}$
and
$a\sqrt{n}=nb$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{n}
&=\dfrac{a}{b}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{b}\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-k}{\sqrt{n}-k}\\
&=\dfrac{a\sqrt{n}-ka}{b\sqrt{n}-kb}\\
&=\dfrac{nb-ka}{a-kb}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$,
$k
\lt \sqrt{n}=\dfrac{a}{b}
\lt k+1
$
so
$kb < a < kb+b$
or
$0 < a-kb < b
$.

This new fraction
for $\sqrt{n}$
has a smaller denominator
than $\dfrac{a}{b}$,
and this can be arbitrarily continued.

By infinite descent,
this is impossible,
so there is a contradiction.

---

To not use the actual
$\sqrt{n}$,
it seems to me that
we have to start with
$n=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$
and then derive a contradiction.

I will now try
to mimic the proof above
and show where it fails.

Again,
assume
$k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$.

Suppose
$n=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$,
so $a^2=nb^2$
and
$na^2=n^2b^2$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
n
&=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\dfrac{n-k^2}{n-k^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a^2n-k^2a^2}{b^2n-k^2b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{n^2b^2-k^2a^2}{a^2-k^2b^2}\\
\end{array}
$

What we want
at this point,
to apply infinite descent,
is that
$a^2-k^2b^2
\lt b^2$.

However,
all I can get is this:

Since
$k^2 < n=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} < (k+1)^2$,
$k^2b^2 < a^2 < (k+1)^2b^2$
so
$0 < a^2-k^2b^2
\lt (2k+1)b^2
$
and this is not good enough.

So,
can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Not that I'm some kind of number theory expert, but it looks doubtful, to my eyes. When you multiply $n - k^2$, top and bottom, to $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$, you introduce a rather large factor of $\sqrt{n} + k$ that wasn't there previously. Moreover, you don't seem to use the fact that $n$ is an integer anywhere; it could just be a square rational number between two consecutive square integers.

Comment: How can you prove that something is irrational without using rationals? Rationals are literally embedded in the term "irrational", and I mean definition, not word. That's just impossible.

Comment: @freakish I believe the question is not about excluding rationals, but about excluding $\sqrt{n}$. While "rewritten only using integers" sounds like rationals are begin excluded, I believe quotients of integers are still "using integers" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Both $k^2$ and $n$ are integers, with $k^2 < n$. Thus $n - k^2 \geq 1$. Therefore, $a^2 - k^2b^2 \geq b^2$.

Final edit: I am certain that $a^2 - k^2b^2 \geq b^2$, and I can now see that your identity comes from:
$$a = \sqrt{n}b \\ b = \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$$ To be clear, your proof cannot work in the second case because:
$$a^2 - k^2b^2 = b^2(n - k^2) \geq b^2$$
But this trick functions in the first proof as:
$$a-kb = b(\sqrt{n}-k) < b$$
You don't actually need to use the inequality manipulation that you have at the end, once you can show that $a-kb$ is an integer, and it is less than $b$ (as you multiplied $b$ by a number smaller than $1$), your conclusion follows immediately.